# Is it possible to make folders (or fragments) on SO?

Tags: feature-request

In order to store questions asked, or marked favorite, belonging to different programming languages or concepts or anything. Like different folders for python, Matlab, graph theory etc. I mean just like we can do in gmail.

Feel free to edit the question in case it needs to. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Search for: `infavorites:mine [tag]`. You can then bookmark the resulting URL.

There is, however, no existing system to do such a thing.

Comment: unfortunately infavorites: is no longer possible -- this was too hard to do in Lucene when we switched, but I do want to bring it back at some point.

Answer (score 2):

Right now you can do this with bookmarks:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python or sqlalchemy or django or pylons
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php or php5 or zend or kohana
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript or jquery
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/math or algorithms
```

In chromium, you can have a folder on your bookmarks bar that just has your different SO bookmarks in it.

Comment: "In order to store questions asked, or marked favorite" -- not quite what the OP asked